# google charts API - how can I initialize it from within body?

Tags: php, api, google-api

This is how pie chart is constructed using google API:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_preparing_data

All seems straightforward, but how can I implement this, if I get my data inside body of html document via php function?

My data looks like this... 
dataset 1:

```
male:4
female:2
?:15
```

dataset 2:

```
Array
(
    [26] =&gt; 2
    [] =&gt; 15
    [18] =&gt; 1
    [28] =&gt; 1
    [22] =&gt; 1
    [21] =&gt; 1
)
```

So how do I get these variables inside google API javascript `var data`      ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for help, I just pasted script inside body and echoed out required data via php.